# Unable to get access token to sharepoint online addin using c# Console application

Tags: sharepoint-online, access-token

For the past few days, I tried all the ways possible. But couldn't get the access token for accessing Sharepoint online addin using c# console application. However I was able to get the access token from POSTMAN.

I couldn't get any reasonable answer over the internet. I am framing a webrequest and passing the details like Client ID, Client Secret, Tenant, Resource etc similar to framing a POSTMAN request but always getting 401 Unauthorized.

Always getting this message:"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Answer (score 0):

Try demo in my previous test thread.

[App Only Token Issue: Unauthorized access](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d33f5818-f112-42fb-becf-3cf14ac5f940/app-only-token-issue-unauthorized-access?forum=appsforsharepoint)

```
Uri siteUri = site url;

//Get the realm for the URL
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);

//Get the access token for the URL.  
//   Requires this app to be registered with the tenant
string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
    TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal,
    siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;

//Get client context with access token
using (var clientContext =
    TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
        siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
{
    var web = clientContext.Web;
    var lib = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDoc");
    var item = lib.GetItemById(3);
    var file = item.File;
    clientContext.Load(file);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I will try this and let you know...

Comment: Tried installing similar package as per your test..but get this error...The package 'AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit' tried to add a framework reference to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
Reference unavailable...can you suggest if this package is the correct one...as already tried installing to GAC..

Comment: Thank you for your help Ganesh & Lee..I was able to get the access token with the test approach you suggested.